# APK Expnsion ZIP - Dealing with lots of high res images?

Tags: android, image, android-asynctask, android-image, apk-expansion-files

I am working on an application that requires quite a few high resolution images to be shown in a gallery.

Due to the APK size restriction, the images have been put in a expansion zip.

I got the gallery working with the expansion file, but it is blocking the main thread, as it seems to read the images one by one and if the gallery needs to show a lot of images, I'm left waiting for the operation to complete.

What are my options here?

Should I unzip the expansion file (in the main activity?) to the internal memory and read the images that way?

Or is there a way to read and load the images asynchronously?

Comment: Did you try image recompression first? E.g. for png files you can run optipng which trys to get in up to 1024 tries the best compression of your image. (Without loosing any informations!). Also try stripping out all metainformations. That could shringe the size of my app by up to 30%.

Comment: They are JPGs (supplied via the client) and have already been compressed (each one is around 400kb now). My question is really about how to deal with loading the images, not with compression.

Comment: You could load **thumbnails** only, in order not to blow the user device's memory. And fully load the selected image only.

Comment: Well, i added in some thumbnails to my expansion file, all 4-5kb. When I try to open a gallery that shows just 3 thumbnails, the operation is still very slow, taking about 5-6 seconds.

Comment: Maybe this link will help you reach your goal: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-displaying-images-with-an-enhanced-gallery--mobile-11130

Comment: That tutorial is about creating a gallery, it doesn't deal with the usage of an Expansion file. the fact that using the Expansion file and loading 3 tiny thumbnails takes a good 5 seconds is an issue, which I'd like help resolving.

Comment: How much time it takes to load those images into your activity?

Comment: Read my above comment. Sometimes, loading just 3 thumbnails, from the expansion file, took up to 6 seconds.